# Accessing a pointer to a member class which stores a pointer to another member class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have one class with point to a data storage member class (Inputs):

```
class Calc
{
public:
    Calc(Inputs *input) : input(input) {}
    void performCalc();
private:
    Inputs *input;
};
```

In the Inputs class I store various data inputs:

```
class Inputs
{
public:
    Inputs(std::string &directory, LogFile &log);
    ~Inputs();

private:

    WriteLogFile &writeToLog;
    WeatherData *weather;
    EvaporationData *evaporation;

friend class Calc;

}
```

Now, when I am in the performCalc() method, I can't I access my weather class in the inputs object which is a member of the Calc class using pointer notation?

```
input->weather    //does not work
```

Nor does the dot notation work (which I didn't think it would, since nothing is linked passed by reference here.)

```
input.weather    //does not work
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**  Sorry!  I forgot to mention that the Calc class is already a `friend class` to the Inputs class.

Comment: `weather` is private in `Inputs` and consequently can't be accessed from outside of `Inputs` unless you declare the class or function `friend`.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `weather` as a private member of `Inputs`, so it isn't visible to your `Calc` object. You have 3 options:

1. Make `weather` public.
2. Make `Calc` a friend of `Inputs`.
3. Create a getter method for `weather` (Recommended, since it improves encapsulation)

Answer (score 0):

Since 'weather' member of 'Input' class is in private field and you're trying to access from Calc class' 'performCalc' method, which is outside of Input class. I think thats the reasone both above doesn't work.

Put 'weather' variable into public field of Input class or try below, using get() methods to access private field of Input class.

```
class Inputs
{    
public:
    Inputs(std::string &directory, LogFile &log);
    ~Inputs();
    WeatherData* getWeatherData(){

     return weather ;
    }
private:

    WriteLogFile &writeToLog;
    WeatherData *weather;
    EvaporationData *evaporation;
}
```